# Youtube API upload from website WITH diff. TITLES

Tags: php, input, youtube-api, title

I am using this code to make a upload-form for my website.
[Youtubeuploader](http://rubensargsyan.com/generate-youtube-video-browser-based-uploading-form-by-php/)

It works perfect, but I got ONE problem.
I want a  form to define the title.
Right now, all the videos are given the title "Example"
I want the user to write their own title for their video.

I've tried making a input with id and name "title", and tried to use $_POST['title'], but it didn't work. The video didn't even upload.

Anyone knows how to do this?
I've looked at all the YouTube Data API code and tried everything.

- Thanks.

Comment: You're probably submitting an empty title to it, I can't think of any other reason. Double-check that `$_POST['title']` is not empty. Also, accept some answers in Stack Overflow!

Comment: I'm sure it's not empty..

sorry.. I keep forgetting..
still waiting for the right answer on this one..

When I add the $_POST['title'], it doesn't even post the video.

Answer (score 0):

Given the link you posted, you have to give `$youtube_video_title` the value from your form.

I mean like this (not secure, always sanitize and filter):

`$youtube_video_title = $_POST['title'];`

**UPDATE :**

try to replace the form code with this one

```
<form action="<?php echo($response->url); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForFile();">
  Title : <input id="title" type="text" name="title"/>
  <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
  <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
    You need to specify a file.
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($response->token); ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" value="go" />

</form>
```

Comment: As I say, I've already tried this, but when I do it the video isn't being uploaded. Nothing happens.

Comment: You can see the code on this link:
(http://rubensargsyan.com/generate-youtube-video-browser-based-uploading-form-by-php/)

If I change $youtube_video_title = "Example"; to $youtube_video_title = $_POST['title'];
NOTHING happens when I try uploading a video.

Comment: The only reason can be that `$_POST['title']` is empty (try `var_dump()`) or it contains non-allowed characters. However, YouTube always returns an error message, check that out.

Comment: @SabineQuardon : if you have the exact same code than your link, then $_POST['title'] is not even initialized. Please see my update for a sample code.

Comment: @Justin T. : I've tried, it didn't work either.
I kinda think it's just YouTube who doesn't allow it when it's a browserbased upload.
I've tried the Zend framework too, but I don't want the user to generate an authentication link before uploading. (http://sabinequardon.dk/test/ZendGdata/demos/Zend/Gdata/YouTubeVideoApp/index.php)
Then I got the wordpress youtubeuploader - but that's only admin who can upload. (Maybe I can make this one to frontend?)